# Type my own font style onto my computer!

Tags: tex-core, metafont

How can I use plain TeX & `metafont` to attain my own font-style, i.e. I want to type the words I write by my hand.

Comment: Related: [Handwriting fonts, METAFONT and OpenType](http://www.ntg.nl/EuroTeX2009/slides/piska-slides.pdf).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: @Rico,@mOnhawk,I have visited the sit you provide for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

plain tex doesn't come into it much (you can use these things with any tex or pdftex format).

there are several metafont "handwriting" fonts on the archive.  the earliest i recall is
peter vanroose's, which you can download from [ctan](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/script.zip) (or browse the [ctan directory](http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/script/), to get a feel for what it involves.  (unfortunately, it's not distributed with tex live or miktex.)

personally, i never got around to "proper" fonts with metafont, having stumbled a lot with creating a symbol font for a place i worked at.

Comment: You mean that I can use the fonts the system provide for me. But I would like to have my own fonts. Just show me a picture of your type character of you hand-writing.